# Get value of managed property in display template using javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, managed-property

```
<body>
<div id="Item">
<!--#_
var siteURL = SP.PageContextInfo.get_siteServerRelativeUrl();
var linkURL = $getItemValue(ctx, "Path");
linkURL.overrideValueRenderer($urlHtmlEncode);
var title = $getItemValue(ctx, "Title");
var description = $getItemValue(ctx, "Description");
var pictureURL = $getItemValue(ctx, "PictureURL");
var customURL = $getItemValue(ctx, "SliderURL");
 _#-->

    <a href="_#= customURL =#_">
    <img src="_#= pictureURL =#_" alt="_#= $htmlEncode(title) =#_">
    </a>
</div>
</body>
```

The var customURL is not retrieving any data. I cannot figure out why.

I have a custom field called SliderURL in a library called "Slider". I created a managed property called SliderURL and mapped it to the custom field in the "Slider" library.

Mapped them in the begginning of the item template:

```
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">&#39;Title&#39;:&#39;Title&#39;,&#39;Path&#39;:&#39;Path&#39;,&#39;Description&#39;:&#39;Description&#39;,&#39;PictureURL&#39;:&#39;PictureURL&#39;,&#39;SliderURL&#39;:&#39;SliderURL&#39;</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this actually worked. I had to re-index the library "Slider" and it took effect immediately.